# Discrete Mathematics: Counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, lattice-orders

Consider an infinite grid labeled with ordered pairs of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$.

You want to move a tile from one intersection of the grid to another and the only valid moves are up(North) or to the right(East).

How many ways are there to go from $(2,3)$ to $(52,33)$ passing through $(27,23)$?

Also, what if our starting point is $(4,5)$ and we're asked to get to $(2,3)$? What can I say? (since we can only go North and East)

Comment: First, please share your thoughts, and you work, in trying to address this problem.  We work *with you*, but not *for you*.

Comment: Are you familiar with combinations/binomial coefficients/${n\choose k}$?

Comment: Sorry, just a second.

Comment: From $(2,3)$ to $(27,23)$, how many times in total do you have to go up by a unit? How many times in total do you have to go right by a unit? If you have to go right for $x$ times and go up $y$ times, in how many ways can you sequence them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can only go up or right, partition the path into two independent parts $(2,3)$ to $(27,23)$ and $(27,23)$ to $(52,53)$. The first part has 25 right and 20 up steps, so there are $45\choose 25$ ways to do it. Similarly the second part has $35\choose 25$ possibilities so the whole path can be drawn in $\binom{45}{25} \binom{35}{25}$ ways.

In the second question there are no paths from $(4,5)$ to $(2,3)$ so the answer is $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much, Akababa. At first I was thinking about adding them up, but then I realized it didn't work. :)